# Peak Height of $\operatorname{sinc}^2(x)$

Tags: calculus

Consider the following equation,

$$f(\omega) = \frac{\Omega ^2}{\hbar^2}\frac{\sin^2[ (\omega_0 - \omega)t/2]}{(\omega_0 - \omega)^2}$$

As a function of $t$, the graphs looks like $\sin^2t$. As a function of $\omega$, the graph looks like $\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc} \sinc ^2(x)$ shifted over to $\omega = \omega_0$. My textbook then says that $f(\omega)$ has a peak height of
$$\bigg( \frac{\Omega t}{2\hbar} \bigg)^2$$

My question is, how did they get this peak height? If the $\sinc^2$ function was only a function of $w$ and not $t$, I'd imagine that the peak height would be just $(\Omega/\hbar)^2$

Comment: Use $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Taylor series at $x=0$ of  $$g(x) = \left(\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\right)^2
= \left(a-\frac{1}{6}a^3x^2+O(x^4)\right)^2
= a^2- \frac{1}{3}a^4x^2+O(x^4)$$
Now substitute $a=\frac{t}{2},\,x=\omega-\omega_0,\,$ multiply with $\frac{\Omega ^2}{\hbar^2}$ and get

$$f(\omega_0) = \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^2 \times \frac{\Omega ^2}{\hbar^2} = \left( \frac{\Omega t}{2\hbar} \right)^2$$